# How to get values of different rows but in same column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, subquery, rows

I have a mysql table like this

```
product |   dist1   |   dist2  |   dist3
--------|-----------|----------|--------
table   |    250    |    320   |    450
desk    |    254    |    145   |    145
chair   |    854    |    544   |    845
bed     |    145    |    265   |    188
```

Now I want to get all product and value only in dist1. I need a result like this. And also how to insert dist5 ?

```
product |   dist1   |
--------|-----------|
table   |    250    |
desk    |    254    |
chair   |    854    |
bed     |    145    |
```

Comment: Not clear can you add the desired result set in your question

Comment: `SELECT product, dist1 FROM my_table;` Something like this is what you  want?

Comment: Do you want to create a new table? Is it like transforming data from one form to another? Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan : second table is the desired output. And how to get this using php (using while loop?)

Comment: You just need to execute the sql chuthan20 mentioned in the comment. Did you try that?

Comment: I think you should follow some basic tutorials on mysql and how to access database using php.

Answer (score 1):

Union with same alias for the second column.

```
select column1, column2 as column from table

Union

Select column1, column3 as column from table
```

If you want single column modify the above as

```
Select column1 as column from table
Union
Select column2 as column from table
```

Based on your edits

```
Select column1, column2 from table
```

will give you two columns from the table. To add a new column first you need to

```
Alter table table1
Add column column1 datatype
```

Then insert data into this new column. If you want some default data like 0 for integers

```
Alter table table1
Add column column1 int default 0
```

Go through these tutorials http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 0):

read only product and dist1 from a table named yourProductTable:

```
SELECT product, dist1 FROM yourProductTable
```

Insert dist5 (do you want to insert a colum named dist5 ?:

```
ALTER TABLE yourProductTable ADD dist5 INT(20)
```